# How can I identify my Wifi network device?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I'm trying to use Ubuntu on a Mediacom Flexbook 13.3 (model M-FB131E).
The Wifi card doesn't seem to be recognized.

Running `lspci` produces:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 22)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers (rev 22)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 22)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 22)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 22)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 22)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 22)
```

Running `lsusb` produces:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:0230 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 3D Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1018:1006  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.` is the USB Ethernet adapter that I'm temporarily using.

None of the listed devices seem to be the Wifi card. How can I find out what
Wifi device is actually inside this netbook, so I can start looking for the right drivers?

Thanks!

***UPDATE***

`0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.`  is a USB hub.

Running `sudo lshw | grep -i -A5 wireless` doesn't produce anything.

I can't find anything about switching Wifi on/off in the BIOS.

Comment: You'd need to search for the IDs. It could be 0bda:5411 by realtek, might be something new.

Comment: It also might be an SDIO device. Please edit your question to add the result of: `dmesg | grep -i sdio` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Ensure the wifi device is enabled//on..  My netbook allows the device to be disabled (switch or in bios), and when disabled GNU/Linux (Ubuntu) doesn't see the device at all.

Comment: Run command `sudo lshw | grep -i -A5 wireless` and add results into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your USB ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/armbian/firmware/master/brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.txt
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.

Answer (score 1):

Running `dmesg | grep -i sdio` (finally) produces:

```
[    3.396231] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[   37.677841] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.bin for chip 0x00a9a6(43430) rev 0x000000
[   37.686764] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.txt failed with error -2
[   38.704097] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[   39.712130] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

So I guess the mistery is solved! The sound card appears to be a Broadcom BCM43430. I'm trying something from https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9791523/ to solve the issue, haven't succeeded yet, but I don't want to go OT.

Maybe it would be useful to add the `dmesg | grep -i sdio` command to  https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en but I didn't see a link to suggest an update.

Thanks everyone!